# search for a string inside html source with python (3.3.1)

Tags: python, string, split

I am working on a project to get  information from a web page.
in the html source I have the following:

**Resultado de Busca:** Foram encontrados **264** casais

I need to get the number between "encontrados" and "casais"

is there anyway in Python to do that? what string function should i use? i want o avoid using regular expression in this case.

```
import urllib.request
f = urllib.request.urlopen("http://listadecasamento.fastshop.com.br/ListaCasamento/ListaCasamentoBusca.aspx?Data=2013-06-07")
s = f.read()

print(s.split())
```

I got this so far, but now I am having trouble finding the number I need.

```
import urllib.request
f = urllib.request.urlopen("http://listadecasamento.fastshop.com.br/ListaCasamento/ListaCasamentoBusca.aspx?Data=2013-06-07")
s = f.read()

num = int(s[s.index("encontrados")+len("encontrados"):s.index("casais")])
```

this give me the error bellow

TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend using a library such as [Beautiful Soup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4) if it's HTML you want to parse. No need for regex.

**EDIT**

Using the URL you just added, this is the sample code to get the HTML object out:

```
import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib

data = urllib.urlopen('http://listadecasamento.fastshop.com.br/ListaCasamento/ListaCasamentoBusca.aspx?Data=2013-06-07').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(data)
element = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': re.compile(r".*\btxt_resultad_busca_casamento\b.*")})
print element.text
```

This will find the HTML `span` element on the page that has the class `txt_resultad_busca_casamento`, which I believe is the data you're trying to extract. From there you can just parse the `.text` attribute to get the exact data you're interested in.

**EDIT 2**

Oops, just realised that uses regular expressions... it seems class matching in BeautifulSoup isn't perfect! This line should work instead, at least until the site changes their HTML:

```
element = soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'ctl00_body_uppBusca'}).find('span')
```

Comment: Not a problem. I would have helped with parsing the actual data, but that URL seems to return "Não foram encontrados casais" rather than "Resultado de Busca: Foram encontrados 264 casais".

Answer (score 1):

Given that you can't parse html with regular expression, if you treat your file as a bag of text you have to use regex or something like:

```
a = 'Resultado de Busca: Foram encontrados 264 casais' #your page text
num = int(a[a.index("encontrados")+len("encontrados"):a.index("casais")])
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you positive of the format of that string?  If you have a string like that (and always will) you can use:

```
s = "Resultado de Busca: Foram encontrados 264 casais"
items = s.split()
```

Your number would be indexed at 5 in items.